# F# RX converting async patterns to Observable sequences

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I want to convert some C# for RX into F# code.
The following is the C# code:

```
Stream inputStream = Console.OpenStandardInput();
var read = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int, int>    
    (inputStream.BeginRead, inputStream.EndRead);
byte[] someBytes = new byte[10];
IObservable<int> source = read(someBytes, 0, 10);
IDisposable subscription = source.Subscribe(
                        x => Console.WriteLine("OnNext: {0}", x),
                        ex => Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}",                                   ex.Message),
                        () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted"));
Console.ReadKey();
```

The following is my code in F#:

```
#light
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
open System.Reactive
open System.Reactive.Linq
open System.Reactive.Subjects
open System.Threading
open System.IO

let inputStream: Stream = Console.OpenStandardInput()
let read = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int, int>(inputStream.BeginRead, inputStream.EndRead)
let someBytes: byte[] = Array.create 10 (byte(0))
let source: IObservable<int> = read(someBytes, 0, 10)

let subscription:IDisposable = 
                 source.Subscribe((fun x -> printfn "OnNext %A" x), 
                               (fun ex -> printfn "OnError %A" ex.Message), 
                               (fun _ -> printfn "OnComplete"))
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

But I got the following compiler errors:

> Error 1 No overloads match for method 'FromAsyncPattern'. The
>   available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window).
>
> Error 2 Possible overload:
>   'Observable.FromAsyncPattern<'TResult>(begin:
>   Func<AsyncCallback,obj,IAsyncResult>, end:
>   Func<IAsyncResult,'TResult>) : Func<IObservable<'TResult>>'.
>
> Error 3 Possible overload:
>   'Observable.FromAsyncPattern<'T1,'TResult>(begin:
>   Func<'T1,AsyncCallback,obj,IAsyncResult>, end:
>   Func<IAsyncResult,'TResult>) : Func<'T1,IObservable<'TResult>>'.

It seems the compiler in F# did not recognize the overload, but I don't know how to make F# compiler smarter to do its job.
Please show me your code.
Thanks and have a nice weekend.
John

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the arguments to FromAsyncPattern are delegates (of type `Func<...>`) rather than F# functions (of type `_->_`).  Therefore, you can't just pass a method (like `inputStream.BeginRead`), but need to pass either an explicit function (e.g. `fun a b c d e -> inputStream.BeginRead(a,b,c,d,e)`) or explicitly construct a delegate (e.g. `System.Func<_,_,_,_,_,_>(fun a b c d e -> inputStream.BeginRead(a,b,c,d,e))`).

In your case, I think that

```
let read = Observable.FromAsyncPattern(
            (fun a b c d e -> inputStream.BeginRead(a,b,c,d,e)), 
            fun r -> inputStream.EndRead r)
```

should work.

Comment: Hi, can you show me the complete code for your explanation, so I will understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnJohn - I've added a complete example, though I don't have RX on my computer to verify that it will work.

Comment: kvb: Thank you, I changed my code according to your advice.
But I got the following compiler error:
Error: The member or object constructor 'FromAsyncPattern' taking 2 arguments are not accessible from this code location. All accessible versions of method 'FromAsyncPattern' take 2 arguments.

Comment: Hello, kvb: I think it is better that you install RX in your PC, and try to play with it, and let me know how I can make the code works.
I can not figure out the difficult syntax, therefore, I can not use it.
But, if C# can do this, I still belive F# can do the same.
Thanks,

Comment: @JohnJohn - Hi John - I may install RX when I get a chance, but I can't promise to do this in the next few days.  I think that your best bet is to try to solve the problem on your own in the meantime.

Comment: @JohnJohn - I've updated my answer; see if that works for you.

Comment: Using System.Func I think this can be written like so: ``System.Func<_,_,_,_,_,_>(inputStream.BeginRead)`` but it's a wild guess as I didn't try.

Comment: @DavidGrenier - I believe that's incorrect; delegate constructors (like `System.Func<_,_,_,_,_,_>(...)`) take their arguments in curried form, but `inputStream.BeginRead` is in tupled form so you can't just pass it directly.